When to use "over" or "under" in describing relationships
I often see the terms "over" and "under" in various mathematical contexts, but I’m not clear on when each should be used. Examples I have encountered:
Over:
A vector space $V$ over a field $F$, where the field $F$ provides the scalars for the vector space.
A Riemann surface lies over the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$.
Generally we use "under" when we refer to the behavior of an object with respect to an action or transformation, but I have also seen:
A subgroup $H$ lies under a group $G$
if $g \in G$ is an element of a group $G$, the element $hgh^{−1}$ is called the conjugate of $g$ under $h$.
When the perspective of the relationship changes, so does the use of "over" or "under". For example, we describe the fiber of $f$ over $b$, but the preimage of $B$ under $f$.
What is the intuition behind certain choosing "over" or "under" in a particular instance?

There is probably no unified reason. Different fields may be developed by people from different countries. So the French will use their prepositions in a different way from the German, and those would translate to "over"/"under" in English, resulting in very inconsistent usages.

The field is considered to be a "base" field, so the vector space is over it.
